# Cant get rid of Soft WDT reset using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, web-server, reset, memory, watchdog

Im using **ESP12E DevKit v2** (esp8266 wifi module) board for controlling relays and displaying DHT22 temp,humidity on web server. It runs smoothly but after while i always get a watchdog timer reset. (If i have serial monitor opened up it happens quicker)

I tried adding more delays, yield function, removing serial prints that i use for debugging but nothing helps.
I think it can be caused because my website is being refreshed every 1sec, because i want to display current time and most recent temp,humidity and this was the easiest way to do it. But this WDT reset problem appeared just recently after i added more code and functionality to my site.

Could anyone have a look at my code and give me some advice on what could help or cause the problem?

**Arduino code:**

```cpp
// Including the needed libraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 // Defining DHT sensor type

// Network details
const char* ssid = "Connection1";
const char* password = "pass";

// Define NTP Client to get time
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Decode HTTP GET value
String valueString = "0";
int pos1 = 0;
int pos2 = 0;

// Variables to store the current output state
String relay0State = "on";
String relay1State = "off";
String relay2State = "off";
String brightness = "0";

// Variables to save date and time
String formattedDate;
String dayStamp;
String timeStamp;

// Variables assigned to pins
const int relay0 = 16;
const int relay1 = 5;
const int relay2 = 4;
const int DHT1Pin = 0;
const int DHT2Pin = 2;

// Initialize DHT sensors
DHT dht1(DHT1Pin, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht2(DHT2Pin, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(relay0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(relay0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);

  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(3000);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(300);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi CONNECTED with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();

  // Initialize a NTPClient to get time
  timeClient.begin();
  // Setting offset time in seconds to adjust for current timezone -> GMT +1 = 3600
  timeClient.setTimeOffset(3600);
}
void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

   while(!timeClient.update()) {
    timeClient.forceUpdate();
  }
  // The formattedDate comes with the following format 2018-05-28T16:00:13Z
  formattedDate = timeClient.getFormattedDate();
  // Extract date
  int splitT = formattedDate.indexOf("T");
  dayStamp = formattedDate.substring(0, splitT);
  // Extract time
  timeStamp = formattedDate.substring(splitT+1, formattedDate.length()-1);

  if (client) {                             
    Serial.println("NEW CLIENT");          // Printing a message out in the serial port, if a new client connects
    String currentLine = "";                // String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        //Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();

            // Turns the PINs on and off
          if (header.indexOf("GET /0/on") >= 0) {
              relay0State = "on";
              digitalWrite(relay0, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /0/off") >= 0) {
              relay0State = "off";
              digitalWrite(relay0, LOW);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /1/on") >= 0) {
              relay1State = "on";
              digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /1/off") >= 0) {
              relay1State = "off";
              digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /2/on") >= 0) {
              relay2State = "on";
              brightness = "75";
              digitalWrite(relay2, 191);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /2/off") >= 0) {
              relay2State = "off";
              brightness = "0";
              digitalWrite(relay2, 0);
            } 

            // Read humidity 
            float h1 = dht1.readHumidity();
            float h2 = dht2.readHumidity();
            // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
            float t1 = dht1.readTemperature();
            float t2 = dht2.readTemperature();
            // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
            float f1 = dht1.readTemperature(true);
            float f2 = dht2.readTemperature(true);

            // Calculating average temp and humidity from DHT22 sensors
            float temperature = (t1 + t2)/2;
            float temperaturef = (f1 + f2)/2;
            float humidity = (h1 + h2)/2;

            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\" name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>");
            client.println("<style> html {font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; box-sizing: border-box;} h1, h2{width: 100%; color: #444444; font-size: 55px;} h2 {font-size: 30px;} h3, h4 {width: 50%; font-size: 24px; color: #444444; padding: 18px; margin: 10px; border-radius: 35px; margin: 4px auto;} h4 {padding: 5px;} .button {background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;} .button2 {background-color: #555555;} .content {width: 100%; } .light {border-radius: 35px; width: 50%; margin: 4px auto;} .slider {-webkit-appearance: none; width: 30%; height: 10px; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px; background: #d3d3d3; outline: none; } .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { -webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 50%; background: #444444; cursor: pointer;} </style><title>Smart TERA</title> </head> ");
            client.println("<body><div class=\"header\"> <h1>Smart TERA</h1><h2>");
            client.println(timeStamp);
            client.println(" / " + dayStamp);
            client.println("</h2> </div> <div class=\"content\"><h3 style =\"background-color: #ff8000;\">Temperature: ");
            client.println(temperature);
            client.println("&#8451; /  ");
            client.println(temperaturef);
            client.println("&#8457; </h3><h3 style =\"background-color: #4da6ff;\">Humidity: ");
            client.println(humidity);
            client.println("%</h3><div class=\"light\" style=\"background-color: #ffff33;\"><h3>Light Brightness: <span id=\"lightPos\"></span> %</h3> <input class=\"slider\" type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"100\" step=\"25\" value="+brightness+" id=\"myRange\">");
            client.println("<script> var slider = document.getElementById(\"myRange\"); var lightP = document.getElementById(\"lightPos\"); lightP.innerHTML = slider.value; $.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000}); slider.oninput = function() { slider.value = this.value; lightP.innerHTML = this.value; $.get(\"/?value=\" + this.value + \"&\"); {Connection: close};}</script> </div>");

            if(header.indexOf("GET /?value=")>=0) {
                pos1 = header.indexOf('=');
                pos2 = header.indexOf('&');
                valueString = header.substring(pos1+1, pos2);
                if(valueString == "0" ){
                  relay2State = "off";
                  brightness = "0";
                  digitalWrite(relay2, 0);
                } else if (valueString == "25"){
                  relay2State = "on";
                  brightness = "25";
                  digitalWrite(relay2, 64);
                } else if (valueString == "50"){
                  relay2State = "on";
                  brightness = "50";
                  digitalWrite(relay2, 128);
                } else if (valueString == "75"){
                  relay2State = "on";
                  brightness = "75";
                  digitalWrite(relay2, 192);
                } else if (valueString == "100"){
                  relay2State = "on";
                  brightness = "100";
                 digitalWrite(relay2, 255);
                } 
           }
            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for controlling relays 
            client.println("<h4>Rock Heater - State " + relay0State + "</h4>");
            // If the relay0State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (relay0State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/0/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/0/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            } 

            client.println("<h4>Humidifier - State " + relay1State + "</h4>");     
            if (relay1State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/1/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/1/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            }

            client.println("<h4>Light - State " + relay2State + "</h4>");   
            if (relay2State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/2/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/2/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            }
            client.println("</div> </body></html>");

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            yield();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      } yield();
    }
    // Clear the header variable and close the connection
    header = "";
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("CLIENT DISCONNECTED");
   }
}
```

**Error message:**

```cpp
Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffed40 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01b0
3fffeef0:  3ffee990 0abd1a53 60000600 00000001  
3fffef00:  00000000 3ffed9d8 00000000 00000000  
3fffef10:  4022cf78 3ffed9d8 3ffee990 60000600  
3fffef20:  4022f8c1 3ffed9d8 3ffee990 0abd1a53  
3fffef30:  4022f906 3fffdab0 00000000 3fffdcb0  
3fffef40:  3ffee9b8 3fffdab0 00000000 40205d0f  
3fffef50:  40000f49 40000f49 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef60:  40000e19 40001878 00000002 00000000  
3fffef70:  3fffff10 aa55aa55 000000b4 401048e4  
3fffef80:  401048ea 00000002 00000000 3315d4f6  
3fffef90:  4010000d 0c060f10 1427fd57 49e0d507  
3fffefa0:  40100a84 3fffef3c 40100a31 3ffffe88  
3fffefb0:  3fffffc0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3fffefc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffeff0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff000:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff010:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff020:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff030:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff040:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff050:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff060:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff070:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff080:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff090:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff100:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff110:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff120:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff130:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff140:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff150:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff160:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff170:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff180:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff190:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff200:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff210:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff220:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff230:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff240:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff250:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff260:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff270:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff280:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff290:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff300:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff310:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff320:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff330:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff340:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff350:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff360:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff370:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff380:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff390:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff400:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff410:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff420:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff430:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff440:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff450:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff460:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff470:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff480:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff490:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff500:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff510:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff520:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff530:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff540:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff550:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff560:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff570:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff580:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff590:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff600:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff610:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff620:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff630:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff640:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff650:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff660:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff670:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff680:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff690:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff700:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff710:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff720:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff730:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff740:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff750:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff760:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff770:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff780:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff790:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff800:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff810:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff820:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff830:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff840:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff850:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff860:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff870:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff880:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff890:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff900:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff910:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff920:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff930:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff940:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff950:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff960:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff970:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff980:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff990:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffab0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffac0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffad0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffae0:  00000000 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffaf0:  3ffe9680 401047c0 3fff0154 000000fd  
3ffffb00:  00000001 401039e3 3ffed800 3ffed848  
3ffffb10:  40103e46 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffb20:  00000005 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffb30:  00000000 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffb40:  3ffe9680 401047c0 3fff0154 00000000  
3ffffb50:  00000001 401039e3 3ffed800 401022c2  
3ffffb60:  40103e46 00000000 00000000 401022c2  
3ffffb70:  40103729 00040000 7fffffff 00000000  
3ffffb80:  00000022 40103726 00040000 00000000  
3ffffb90:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 401050bd  
3ffffba0:  4000050c 00080000 00002000 4000050c  
3ffffbb0:  40229838 00000030 0000001b ffffffff  
3ffffbc0:  40229836 00000023 00000020 00000005  
3ffffbd0:  3ffe95b4 00000020 3ffe951c 00000000  
3ffffbe0:  00000005 3ffe9514 00000001 3ffecdc8  
3ffffbf0:  3ffef854 00000001 3fff0a30 00000030  
3ffffc00:  3ffe9685 401047db 3ffed110 3ffee2a8  
3ffffc10:  00000000 00000000 00000020 000000fa  
3ffffc20:  00000004 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffc30:  3ffe9684 401047a6 3ffecdc8 401013da  
3ffffc40:  00000005 00000000 00000020 401013da  
3ffffc50:  3ffe9685 401047db 3ffed110 3ffed800  
3ffffc60:  401020f1 3ffed110 3ffed800 000000f4  
3ffffc70:  00007fff 06460509 402296d3 00000001  
3ffffc80:  ffffffff 00000000 3ffe97d1 00000008  
3ffffc90:  40229722 3ffecdf0 3ffef854 00000001  
3ffffca0:  4022982e 3ffecdf0 3ffef854 3ffecdf0  
3ffffcb0:  00000005 00000005 00000008 3fff1250  
3ffffcc0:  3ffe9682 402287df 3ffecdf0 3fff0a68  
3ffffcd0:  00000000 4021ba8b 3ffee2a8 00000022  
3ffffce0:  00000000 00000002 00000000 3ffecdf0  
3ffffcf0:  3fff126a 40104e63 3fff0a68 3ffeffe4  
3ffffd00:  3fff1234 0000002f 00013880 00000001  
3ffffd10:  00000004 4020ddc9 3ffef218 3ffeffe4  
3ffffd20:  3fff126a 0000023f 00000001 3ffeef98  
3ffffd30:  00000000 3ffeef98 4216cccd 00000000  
3ffffd40:  3ffef644 3ffef60c 3fff1234 4020e04b  
3ffffd50:  4000dd1f 3ffef60c 3fff1234 4020e43c  
3ffffd60:  3ffef490 4bc6a7f0 12b020c4 00000000  
3ffffd70:  00000000 00000000 4bc6a7f0 3ffef494  
3ffffd80:  3ffef644 00000000 3ffef60c 40215b14  
3ffffd90:  00000000 3ffee968 019672ab 00000000  
3ffffda0:  00000000 3fff1234 3ffef1b8 00000000  
3ffffdb0:  3ffee990 3ffef1b8 3ffe8510 3fff1234  
3ffffdc0:  3fff1234 3fff0868 3ffef60c 40215d18  
3ffffdd0:  40100000 3ffeef98 00000000 401001cd  
3ffffde0:  3fff1278 3fff0868 3ffef60c 40216730  
3ffffdf0:  3fff0864 402171fc 00000010 401007f4  
3ffffe00:  00000014 3fff0864 000000ff 00000000  
3ffffe10:  00000006 3ffef580 00000284 401007f4  
3ffffe20:  00000055 00000218 3fff0864 3fff0864  
3ffffe30:  3fff07fc 3ffef60c 3fff0b2c 40216778  
3ffffe40:  00000000 4bc6a7f0 676c8b43 00000000  
3ffffe50:  00000000 00000000 4bc6a7f0 00000000  
3ffffe60:  3ffef1dc 000003ef 4010014c 0002bef4  
3ffffe70:  00000000 4bc6a7f0 79db22d0 00000000  
3ffffe80:  032cca97 00000000 3ffe8510 00000000  
3ffffe90:  00000003 3ffe9238 40205d54 3fffefa0  
3ffffea0:  00000003 00000000 3fff05c4 40203a0b  
3ffffeb0:  0328466c 00000000 3fff05c4 40203a5d  
3ffffec0:  00000002 3ffe9235 40205d54 4216cccd  
3ffffed0:  3fffff50 00000000 3fffff50 40205355  
3ffffee0:  3ffe9238 00000000 3fff05c4 40203a5d  
3ffffef0:  0000000d 00000000 7ff80000 402055ca  
3fffff00:  00000002 00000000 3fffff50 40205355  
3fffff10:  3ffe9235 429ab852 3fffff50 4216cccd  
3fffff20:  7fc00000 429ab852 3fffff50 40205714  
3fffff30:  7fc00000 429ab852 3fffff50 40205731  
3fffff40:  7fc00000 429ab852 7fc00000 402029d7  
3fffff50:  40206478 00000000 00001388 4020e7a7  
3fffff60:  00000000 3fff05c4 00000000 00000000  
3fffff70:  00000000 3fff0a8c 0000007f 00000000  
3fffff80:  7fc00000 41c9999a 3ffef0f8 402025a4  
3fffff90:  00000000 00000000 00000001 3ffef160  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffef130 40205e00  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)


 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,6)

wdt reset
```

**EspExceptionDecoder stack trace:**
  [image: stacktrace]

Comment: don't use the String class

Comment: u mean that i change string brightness to int?

Comment: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/the-evils-of-arduino-strings

Comment: thanks that was new for me, but wouldnt that just make WDT reset come later? i want to eliminate it as much as possible

Comment: try the esp exception decoder, it will tell you what line of your code crashes.

Comment: `But this WDT reset problem appeared just recently after i added more code and functionality to my site.` ahhh, "more code", yes, it's always "more code" that does it ... any chance you can share what code you added that broke your ESP?

Comment: i have installed the decoder and posted the stack trace here, there are errors on more lines not just single one.. most of them are memory issues if i understand them correctly